# concatenate row and column at intersection

Tags: concatenation

I want combine the row and column names where they intersect.  I tried to use concatenate with reference cells, but filling down and across requires changing the references of multiple cells.  I am dealing with a large grid (2000 rows x 200 columns).  Is there a formula that will help me fill down and across?

[Before & Desired Results Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFD87.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you need to use is

```
=CONCATENATE($A2, " > ", B$1)
```

`$` sign 'locks' the cell, whereas cell without it is copied across.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!